# Does iOS SDK 4.x support the Keychain Services API in the simulator?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, keychain

Before iOS 4.0 some blogs claim Keychain Services API doesn't run in the simulator. How about iOS 4.0? Does it run now on the sim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They started supporting it in 3.x. I can't remember exactly when but it's certainly there in "modern" versions of the SDK.